# node.js accessing model from different file

Tags: node.js, models

My project looks like this:

[image]

My problem is that im going through a tutorial, http://youtu.be/5e1NEdfs4is .
but i want to handle all paths in index.js that the tutorial does in app.js

In my index.js i do the following:

```
router.route('/api/bears')

//create a bear (Accessed at POST http://localhost:3000/api/bears)
.post(function(req, res) {

    var bear = new Bear();  // create a new instance of the bear model
    bear.name = req.body.name;  // set the bears name (comes from post request)

    //save the bear and check for errors
    bear.save(function(err) {
        if(err)
            res.send(err);

        res.json({ message: 'Bear created!' });
    });
})

// get all the bears (accessed at GET http://localhost/api/bears)
.get(function(req, res) {
    Bear.find(function(err, bears) {
        if(err)
            res.send(err);

        res.json(bears);
    });
});
```

In app.js is this to load all models:

```
//load all files in models dir
fs.readdirSync(__dirname + '/app/models').forEach(function(filename) {
if (~filename.indexOf('js')) require(__dirname + '/app/models/' + filename)
});
```

and in index.js i want to declare variable:

```
var Bear = require('./app/models/bear');
```

but this doesn't seem to work.

I get the error:

[image]

bear.js if looking like this:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var BearSchema = new Schema({
name: String
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Bear', BearSchema);
```

If im doing something superwrong with node.js it's because im very new to it and have never used javascript at all.

thankful for all help I can get!

Comment: Can you show bear.js plz ?

Comment: Okay, can you screen your project tree please ?

Comment: I see now that my folder structure is not showing right, updating with picture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so it seems that you have to get back from one folder.

In fact, with nodejs, you have to specify the path FROM your current directory.

If you need to require bear in index.js (which is in route folder) you'll have to make something like :

```
var Bear = require('../yourfolder')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access by this:

```
var Bear = require('../models/bear');
```

Comment: My code crashes then, cant find module './models/bear'.
Also tested this before the question. 
But thanks anyway!